# JavaScript unintentionally "translates" DOM element id string into DOM object reference?

Tags: javascript

Lets assume I have this code:

```
function foo (id_of_dom_element, number){

    document.getElementById(id_of_dom_element).innerHTML=number;
    number = number + 1;
    setTimeout("foo(" + id_of_dom_element + "," + number + ")", 1000);
}
```

Initial call to the function:

```
foo("countdown", 0);
```

What happens:

- At first iteration, everything works like it should
- At second iteration however, "id_of_dom_element" is no longer a string but a DOM object reference??

Questions:

- Why is this happening (I don't even know how to search for this phenomenon)?
- How can I prevent that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Side note: it'd be more accurate to use setInterval if you're counting real-time seconds. The setTimeout callback is guaranteed to be called *at least* 1000ms after the setTimeout call, but if it is delayed even a little for some reason (e.g. other JavaScript code running at the time), the delay will be propagated. On the other hand, setInterval will try to fire the callback regularly every 1000ms after the initial call.

Comment: @Touffy actually, most people recommend the opposite, and for accurate timing would dynamically adjust the 1000 counter to account for this.  One of the problems with `setInterval` is that if the browser can't service the callback then they stack up, and then all get processed at once when the browser's event loop becomes free.

Comment: Thx. I will consider this...

Comment: Seems unlikely that the JS thread can be held up that long, at least not by other JavaScript. It's not animation code here, it's 1000ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're passing a string as the callback function to `setTimeout` and you're not taking care to ensure that `id_of_dom_element` is passed as a string itself, so instead it refers to the automatically created variable `window[id_of_dom_element]` (i.e. the element itself).

These days passing functions as strings is considered extremely poor practise - don't do it!  Instead, pass an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
     foo(id_of_dom_element, number);
}, 1000);
```

Better yet, you can encapsulate the entire behaviour thus:

```
function elementCounter(id, number) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    (function loop() {
        el.innerHTML = number++;
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    })();  // loop is an "immediately invoked function expression"
}
```

Note that in this version all "state" is enclosed in the outer scope's variables, so the `setTimeout` call merely has to be passed a reference to the `loop` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply!

Its working.

Little typo in your solution:

    setTimeout(function() {
         foo(id_of_dom_element, number);
    } -->)<--*, 1000);

*Must be deleted...

Comment: @HamburgerTS good spot on the typo.   You really ought to consider the second version, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

All elements in the DOM with an ID are made available through a variable that is equal to their id name.

The second time you call the timeout, in the `foo` method, you don't include the quotation marks, so instead of passing a variable `"countdown"` you're passing the variable `countdown` which is equal to the DOM object. You can change your code as

```
function foo (id_of_dom_element, number){

    document.getElementById(id_of_dom_element).innerHTML=number;
    number = number + 1;
    setTimeout("foo('" + id_of_dom_element + "'," + number + ")", 1000);
}
```

Comment: He _could_ change his code that way, but IMHO he shouldn't...   Passing functions as strings is how we wrote JS back in the 1990s.

Comment: Yes, he should definitely go with the anonymous function, but I wanted him to see what error he'd actually made.